# Qt creating a video/AVI file from widget

Tags: c++, qt

Im using QT 5.4.1, and I'm wondering if there is any way of been able to record/capture a widget and save it to a file? Ive done some looking around at some of the QT stuff but none of it seems to be what I need. Im able to capture images as PNG's. Is there a way to make these PNG files into 1 Avi or Gif?

Comment: I don't think Qt has any out of the box solution for this. Qt comes with gstreamer though, you could try and use that.

Comment: I've no specific information, but take a look at one of the multimedia classes like `QCameraImageCapture` or `QMediaRecorder`. It should be possible some how.

Answer (score 0):

ffmpeg could do the trick of making video from the images

```
ffmpeg -framerate 24 -i img%03d.png output.mp4
```

use the QProcess to call it from your qt app once you have the images .

but i think the real issue will be to grab the images in enough speed so that it feels like a video when combined .this will require at least   24 frames per second .That will be an issue since that's too many frames to grab in a second .

i will try to do it in a multi threaded method and share the code if i am  successful .